# my For loop works differently with print and file-write in Python

Tags: python

Here I show a for loop which doesn't work well. What it prints is right while it only writes the last line to the .txt file. For example, 
it prints:

```
[0.173] [robe]
[0.493] [tree]
[0.274] [book]
```

But the file data01.txt has only one line:

```
[0.274] [book]
```

What I expect is the file includes all it prints.

```
for a_word in phrase_model.keys():
    for b_word in phrase_model.keys():
        a_val = phrase_model[a_word]
        b_val = phrase_model[b_word]
        c_word = [a_word, b_word]
        cos_dis = cosine_similarity(a_val, b_val)
        print(str(cos_dis) + str(c_word))
        f = open('data01.txt', 'w')
        f.write(str(cos_dis) + str(c_word))

f.close()
```

Comment: Change ‘w’ to ‘a’.

Comment: Change this `'w'` write mode to `'a'` append mode

Comment: Ideally, you want to open the file once, and write everything to it rather than opening it many times in append mode (and only close it once). Have a look at the [`with open(...`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) syntax.

Comment: [How do you append to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file-in-python) — but you would be better off opening the file before the loop instead of opening it repeatedly inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You open the file for writing repeatedly in each iteration, and thus it is constantly truncated.

Just open the file once before the loops.

```
f = open('data01.txt', 'w')

for a_word in phrase_model.keys():
    for b_word in phrase_model.keys():
        a_val = phrase_model[a_word]
        b_val = phrase_model[b_word]
        c_word = [a_word, b_word]
        cos_dis = cosine_similarity(a_val, b_val)
        print(str(cos_dis) + str(c_word))
        f.write(str(cos_dis) + str(c_word))

f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using write mode

`f = open('data01.txt', 'w')`

Instead you should use append mode

`f = open('data01.txt', 'a')`

This is the reason the lines are overwritten and you see only last line. Do read about different modes [here](https://www.guru99.com/reading-and-writing-files-in-python.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have opened your file in `write` mode.

```
        f = open('data01.txt', 'w')
```

This will start overwriting the file from the beginning.

You should use the `append` mode.

```
        f = open('data01.txt', 'a')
```

This will append to the file instead of overwriting.